# Car Repair Booking WordPress Plugin

Tags: wordpress, appointment

I'm finding for an online booking plugin in wordpress that displays a booking calendar and asks for the customer's specific locations. I've tried birchpress but the problem is that I need to provide a location for my services. What i want is that the customer should provide their location. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Use birchpress and add some custom input fields through the admin console settings for Birchpress.